# Testing typescript asyc functions, Async callback was not invoked even though it's called in .then() method

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jasmine, redux-thunk

I've been searching around for a while for a resolution to this but can't find anything, the only thing I can think of is redux-mock-store doesn't support Promises.

I have this test method below.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { cleanAll } from 'nock';

var middleware = [thunk];
var mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware);

describe('Organisation thunk actions', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        cleanAll();
    });

    describe('getOrganisation', () => {
        test('should create BEGIN_GET_ORGANISATION_AJAX action when getting organsation', (done: any) => {
            jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;
            var expectedAction = [{ type: types.BEGIN_GET_ORGANISATION_AJAX }];
            var store = mockStore({});
            store.dispatch<any>((OrganisationActions.getOrganisation("e"))).then(() => {
                var actions = store.getActions();
                expect(actions).toEqual(expectedAction);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is designed to test the action below.

```
export const getOrganisation = (organisationId: string, expands?: string[]) => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(beginGetOrganisationAjax());
            return OrganisationApi.getOrganisationAsync(organisationId).then((organisation: any) =>     {
            dispatch(getOrganisationSuccess(organisation))
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    }
}
```

Where `OrganisationApi.getOrganisationAsync(organisationId)` is a call to a mockApi that I know works from usage.

When I run this test it fails twice after the 30s DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL specified, once as expected (as I've designed the expect to) but the second failure is an error "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.".

Unless I'm mistaken, the async callback is the `done()` function invoked after the `expect(actions).toEqual(expectedAction)` within the `.then()` function in the test.

As the expect fails the `.then()` is definitely running but doesn't seem to be running the `.done()` function, can anyone see why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue, posting the resolution in case someone has a similar problem.

The Async callback is never called as the test function quits out as soon as it comes across the failing `expect()` statement, therefore it never actually runs the `done()` function in this instance.

Once this test passes it calls the `done()` function and my tests pass.